# Photoshop-like brush ,on android canvas. Blend on stroke

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, paint, blend

I'm trying to implement a bitmap brush and paint her on canvas. The problem is that when I put the brush alpha color, it begins to impose prev. point over the old ones so that the transparency disappears.Like on blend mode.

It must be so, but not at the moment when I draw this stroke. 
Respectfully next stroke must be imposed on all previous stroke layers, 
but not in the current.

[ex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VobFx.png)

How to implement this? I tried using :

paint.setXfermode (new AvoidXfermode (paint Color, 255, AvoidXfermode.Mode.AVOID));

This to avoid the imposition of the current color, but then in the first place in the brush show's whit transparency area. Second does not work on the imposition of the underlying strokes.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    //Draw all dots on tempBitmap - canvas
    for (Vector2 pos : mPositions) 
    {
       tempCanvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapBrush, pos.x, pos.y, paintBrushStyle);
    }
    //Draw on view bitmap
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitMap, 0, 0, drawPaint);
    //Clear all points
    mPositions.clear();
    }


public void setColor(String newColor)
{
  invalidate();
  paintColor = Color.parseColor(newColor);
  paintBrushStyle.setColor(Color.BLACK);
  //Make transp.
  paintBrushStyle.setAlpha(100);
  //set bitmapbrush color
  paintBrushStyle.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(paintColor,PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));

//test to avoid blend
 paintBrushStyle.setXfermode(new AvoidXfermode(paintColor,255, AvoidXfermode.Mode.AVOID));
```

Comment: Have u found the solution?